# Android heap challenge

Tags: android, heap-memory

I wanted to get an idea, for making an app that slowly use heap until app crashes. 
I tried few things, but couldn't come up with a good idea. 
Did anybody tried it before? 
Any ideas?

Thx.

Comment: you are working with image I suppose, right?

Comment: The purpose of the app will be, to slowly struggle heap..

Comment: allocate object in a whileloop - slow down the looping with a timer :-p

Comment: umm did you mean app that stress memory heap...

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a test purpose? Because I really can't wonder why otherwise!

Anyway, one simple thing you could do is to simply load an image from the Gallery every 5 seconds or so and keep them in an arraylist!

*But, that would not be a linear increase since each time the increase would produce a memory spike to occur.*

Comment: It's obviously for testing purposes . but I will need that to be linear increase like I wrote..